# Movie file Blur effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, blur, effect

I want to implement blur effect to Video.
To play video, I use MPMoviePlayerViewController.
But, I don't know how to implement blur effect to movie.
I tried to overlay blur image above the movie so implement blur effect, but it isn't possible.
When video play, It should change with real time. I found libraries to implement image blurr effect, but can't find library to apply blur effect to video with realtime.I use mp4 file for blur effect. I tried to use GPUImage framework, but it doesn't run exactly.
How can implement that?
Please help me.
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe GPUImage from Brad Larson is the best way to achieve.

Following is the excerpt from the github page of GPUImage

```
//Filtering live video

//To filter live video from an iOS device's camera, you can use code like the following:

GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

GPUImageFilter *customFilter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] initWithFragmentShaderFromFile:@"CustomShader"];
GPUImageView *filteredVideoView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, viewWidth, viewHeight)];

// Add the view somewhere so it's visible

[videoCamera addTarget:customFilter];
[customFilter addTarget:filteredVideoView];

[videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

Since GPUImage has open-source code, you can open up the `GPUImageVideoCamera` class and study the portion where it perform the live filtering of video data. Then use Apple's `CoreVideo` framework to  grab the video data of a movie video being played and make this GPUImage portion work for it.

Sometimes, boiler-plate codes are not available, but there's always a way out.. Good luck. :)

Comment: but, the framework doesn't run. it crashes. So I can't use the framework.

Comment: Just go through your import process of GPUImage framework once more. It works pretty well. I've used it. :)